# Get table name from sub-query to use in delete / update / insert clauses in Oracle in one line

Tags: sql, oracle

The goal is to use the table name returned from subselect in insert/update/delete statements. It fails to achieve desired results.

---

If we execute with *TABLE* (TABLE is oracle syntax word as described in [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems014.htm))

```
delete from TABLE
  (select DECODE(this returns table name as string) from REF_TABLE where where_clause);
```

then:
22905. 00000 -  "cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"

---

If we execute without TABLE:

```
delete from
  (select DECODE(this returns table name as string) from REF_TABLE where where_clause);
```

Then it actually deletes from REF_TABLE the record that satisfies when clause.

---

What is a proper way to pass table name from subselect to outer query?

---

[Doc examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm)

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from table :1' USING (select DECODE(...) from REF_TABLE WHERE where_clause);
```

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "delete from table :1" when
>   expecting one of the following:
>
> := . ( @ % ;
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: Hint:  `execute immediate`.  You cannot do this with a single statement.  You have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not want to compile as the error suggests. Why?

Comment: You need to create the string in advance.  You cannot pass an identifier as a parameter.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the goal it in **one line** using 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE' or some other way?

Comment: Why do you need it in one line?  Are you just looking for the simplest solution or is there some weird tool restriction you have to work around?  Sandeep's answer below is a single statement and arguably "one line of code".  That's a bit of a stretch, but you could put that PL/SQL logic inside a WITH clause for a SELECT, and run it all in a single SELECT statement which most people would consider "one line".  The cleanest solution is probably to create a procedure to do the work and then call the procedure in one line.

Answer (score 1):

You never mention table keyword when executing a DML query for example Insert, update and delete

```
delete from table_name;
update table_name set field='value';
insert into table_name (field) values ('value');
```

Table keyword is mentioned when you are executing a DDL statement like Create, Alter, drop and Truncate

```
Create table table_name (field varchar2(100));
Alter table table_name modify field1 varchar2(1000);
Drop table table_name;
truncate  table table_name;
```

Hence the below query mentioned by you is correct

```
delete from
  (select DECODE(this returns table name as string) from REF_TABLE where where_clause);
```

only limitation with the above query is that you have to use table_name source from a fixed table or view i.e. it cannot be picked from data dictionary views or you will get below error.

```
SQL Error: ORA-02030: can only select from fixed tables/views
02030. 00000 -  "can only select from fixed tables/views"
*Cause:    An attempt is being made to perform an operation other than
           a retrieval from a fixed table/view.
*Action:   You may only select rows from fixed tables/views.
```

you can use PL/SQL block similar as mentioned below to delete tables recursively

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c
  IS
    SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE '%SANDEEP26FEB16_2%';
BEGIN
  FOR c1 IN c
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from ' || c1.table_name;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```